# _vscprintf equivalent on Android?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, printf

`_vscprintf` is not available on Android. Also `vsprintf(NULL, fmt, ap)` does not work (produces seg fault), so there seems to be no way of calculating size of buffer required for vsnprintf to succeed?

Android [sources](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/system/core/liblog/logd_write.c) indicate that `__android_log_print` function just truncates strings to 1024 using vsnprintf...

How do you handle this scenario?

Comment: "vsprintf(NULL, fmt, ap) does not work (produces seg fault)": are you sure you're not using it wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Section [7.19.6.13]—The `vsprintf` function—of the C99 Standard does not state that the output buffer may be `NULL`.

You probably want to use `vsnprintf`:

```
int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap)
```

If the call is successful, the return value is the number of characters that would have been written if the buffer were large enough, excluding the NUL terminator. This is like `_vscprintf`, which also does not include the NUL terminator in its count.

Comment: I got that suggestion from SO post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785381/replacement-for-ms-vscprintf-on-macos-linux), so I tried it even though I've read the docs...

Comment: And thanks for bringing that up, I overlooked that part of the documentation of vsnprintf, which I am actually using to produce the resulting string.