# Replacement for MS vsprintf_s on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm converting C++ code from Windows to work under Linux and I came across this function "vsprintf_s". It is a Microsoft specific function so I would like to ask if there is a replacement in Linux?
Thanks

Comment: See [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) for information about the `*_s()` functions not being directly available via non-Microsoft libraries — eg not available on Linux or Mac OS X.  No, it isn't directly available.  You can get pretty close with `vsnprintf()`, but there are definitely differences in the calling sequences (multiple differences).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785381/replacement-for-ms-vscprintf-on-macos-linux).

Comment: @Martin the link solve the issue for _vscprintf function which is different than vsprintf_s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like vsnprintf() would be a suitable replacement according to [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vsnprintf).

Comment: It's close, but the overflow-handling behaviours are quite different. `vsprintf_s` aborts the program on attempted overflow. `vsnprintf` truncates the output and carries on.